# Is there a document specification for formatting the version query output of an application

Tags: package-management, application-development, format, versions

I'm aware that some recommended standards for Linux package development exist. For example, according to Debian standards, service users and groups should begin with an underscore.

Is there a standard format for providing the application version identifier?  I'm not referring to the Common Platform Enumeration (CPE) format which is independent of Linux.

I'm looking for a standard that would help create a regex to extract application versions using the `strings` command instead of having to execute the application itself such as:

```
$ apache2 -v
Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
```

Would prefer to do something like:

```
strings $(which apache2) | grep <regex-here>
```

Comment: There is no regular expression that will match both the unregulated version number and nothing else. Scrape the package version numbers from `dpkg -l` to see what you're dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

While there are recommended standards for Linux package development, there is no "set" standard. A better approach may be to execute:

```
dpkg -l | grep apache2 | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

And of course, replace "apache2" with the application you want the version of.

Comment: You don't need `sudo ` for `dpkg -l`. "What packages are installed?" is information available to all users. Don't become `root` unnecessarily.

Comment: @waltinator Absolutely correct! I updated my answer. Thx

Comment: `dpkg -l` is a shortcut to `dpkg-query`, and `dpkg-query` can output specific fields: `dpkg-query -f '${Version}\n' -W apache2`

Comment: This is a great answer and I truly appreciate it! However, I don't think this will address my particular use case.  This is because I need to take non-registered application binaries into account.  Say the system is running Docker or another virtualization, and application binaries exist on the server but are not installed or known by the system's package manager.  I can assume that the filename will be correct though. File hash would be nice, but It's virtually impossible to collect the hash for all versions and subversions across every Linux distro.

Comment: @muru `dpkg-query -f '${Version}\n' -W apache2` is a great answer since it avoids name collision such as having `iilibapache2-mod-php8.28.2.4-1` installed and getting confounded that way. However, I can't use this with an arbitrary binary.

Comment: Being able to access a source of verified binary hashes for each Linux distro would also serve this purpose, but I don't know how I could get that either - i.e. whether a maintainer of each distro would (a) have access to them, and (b) be willing to share them.